# Использование в C++ классов Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, embarcadero, delphi-2010

Возможно ли вообще использовать классы, написанные на Delphi и сохранённые в .dcu (Embarcadero RAD Studio 2010), в C++ (Embarcadero RAD Studio 2010).
Если да, то как?

Comment: теоретически да. На практике - нужно правильно угадать версии. Даже у самой делфи dcu между собой не совместимы. Но вообще то для этого придумали bpl.
И да, в dcu никто не сохраняет. В него компилируют:)

Comment: А не могли бы вы объяснить, что с bpl делать?

Comment: [BPL][1]


  [1]: http://wm-help.net/books-online/book/56472/56472-96.html

Answer (score 2):

[Вот](http://www.cyberguru.ru/programming/delphi/visualc-classes.html). Наоборот, но, может быть, поможет

Я слышал, C++Builder может использовать паскалевские файлы в проекте, компилировать их, и использовать их функции...
Попробуйте прикрепить дельфийский файл к вашему проекту

Comment: Пробовал: если инклудаю .pas, то ошибка компиляции в его первой строчке (естественно на делфи файл компилится); если инклудаю .dcu, то ошибка Illegal character. Вот

Comment: стоп. Вы пытаетесь к проекту С++ прикрепить форму из делфи?

Comment: не совсем, я хочу юзать в С++ класс, написанный на Delphi, который содержит TForm и TImage.

Comment: ну тогда, уж наверное, нужно использовать не DCU, а PAS. dcu это уже откомпилированный файл.  
какого рода ошибка выскакивает при использовании pas-файла?

Comment: да, в первой же строчке pas-файла, "unit UnitName;" пишет Declaration syntax error.